# Get intersection points of line and shape

Tags: java, math, geometry, computational-geometry, java-2d

I have a custom shape as shown in image.
Suppose the blue rectangle covering the shape in the image depicts the bounding box of that shape.

**If I draw line at one of the diagonal of the bounding rectangle, how can I get the intersection points (in image they were drawn using green color)?**

I am using Java2D, I have a GeneralPath with all the coordinates from which I draw the shape on the screen.

[image: Custom Shape]

Comment: BTW based on comments I recommend you to check out basic geometry, I don't want to blame you because of lack of memories, but if you work with geometry, it really saves a lot of time if you repeat things. Here is a good site to start: http://www.wolfram.com/

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary i will refresh.

Answer (score 5):

### Idea

You can deconstruct the GenenralPath into its segments (move-to, line-to, quad-to, cubic-to, close) by using the getPathIterator() method. Now you can search per segment for intersections with the line.

```
public static Point[] getIntersections(Path path, Line line) {
    List<Point> intersections = new ArrayList<Point>();
    PathIterator it = path.getPathIterator();
    double[] coords = new double[6];
    double[] pos = new double[2];
    while (!it.isDone()) {
        int type = it.currentSegment(coords);
        switch (type) {
        case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
            pos[0] = coords[0];
            pos[1] = coords[1];
            break;
        case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
            Line l = new Line(pos[0], pos[1], coords[0], coords[1]);
            pos[0] = coords[0];
            pos[1] = coords[1];
            Point intersection = getIntersection(line, l);
            if (intersection != null)
                intersections.add(intersection);
            break;
        //...
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("unknown PathIterator segment type: " + type);
        }
        it.next();
    }
    return intersections.toArray(new Point[] {});
}
```

### Line/Line intersections

Line/Line intersections can be computed directly, for example, using vector algebra:

- a 2d point/line is represented by a 3d vector (x, y, w)
- the point (x, y) is represented by (x, y, 1)
- the line through the points p1 and p2 is given by p1 x p2 (cross-product)
- for two lines l1 = (a, b, c) and l2 = (d, e, f) the intersection is given by l1 x l2 (cross-product)
- to project the intersection into 2d you have to divide x and y coordinates by w
- if w = 0 then there is no single point of intersection

### Line/Bezier intersections

A Path can contain quadratic and cubic Bezier curves. To find points of intersection between a line and a Bezier curve, there are several algorithms available, for example:

- de Casteljau subdivision
- Bezier clipping
- Newton's method
- polynomial root finding

De Casteljau subdivision is easy to implement but has some issues in relatively rare cases. If you do not want to use a math library which can compute the intersections for you, I recommend implementing de Casteljau subdivision.

Edit: Another alternative would be to approximate the Bezier curve segments of the Path by a number of line segments. Then you only need to find line/line intersections.

Comment: where is the getIntersection method ?

Comment: @Mihir, you have to write that method yourself. It should compute the intersection point of two line segments.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list of points defining the shape. Place the (x,y) in the equation of the line, and see if it 'solves'. Pseudocode -

```
int threshold = 0.01
for point in points: 
  if (point.y - m * point.x + c)^2 < threshold : 
    print "solution found"
```

Comment: @Mihir Those are the parameters of the line. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_%28geometry%29

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary i don;t remember the maths much , i have line x1,y1 and x2,y2 can you give me an example how can i convert this 2 line points to line parameter ?

Comment: @Mihir sure: you need to use it like this: x1*x + y1*y = x2 + y2 then you go for explain y. y1*y = x2 + y2 - x1*x then you just divide by y1 so the final answer: y = (x2/y1 + y2/y1) - (x1/y1)*x there you go, in the first () you find c, in the second () you find m

Comment: I don't think this answer is very helpful. Testing all points of the shape is *expensive*.

Comment: @Matthias true! could be more optimized if you can find two points on the line on the two sides of the shape, then you can use binary search. I give it back the -1 to 0 because this can be the base of the solution.

Comment: @Matthias then provide me the optimized answer.